# Is it possible to create a csv string that orders by given positions using linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado

I'm creating a value converter that receives (object value) as parameter. Those are numbers of the object `DrawNumber`. I want to convert these numbers into a string separated by commas but the numbers have to be in the right position (`Position` is a property from `DrawNumber`). Is this possible to do in LINQ?

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    IEnumerable<DrawNumber> numbers = (IEnumerable<DrawNumber>)value;
    List<DrawNumber> numberList = new List<DrawNumber>(numbers);
    var csv = string.Join(",", numberList);
    // this doesnt order it based on position
}
```

```
public class DrawNumber
{
    public int DrawId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int? Position { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `numberList = numbers.OrderBy(x=>x.Position);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OrderBy`.  Since `Position` is nullable (`int?`) you might want to have the null values appear first.  In that case you should use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`:

```
var numberList = numbers.OrderBy(n => n.Position.HasValue)
                        .ThenBy(n => n.Position)
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place objects with null position on beginning of enumerable

```
string.Join(",", numberList.OrderBy(n => n.Position == null).ThenBy(n => n.Position).Select(n => n.Number))
```

If you want to place objects with null position on end of enumerable

```
string.Join(",", numberList.OrderBy(n => n.Position != null).ThenBy(n => n.Position).Select(n => n.Number))
```

if you don't want to place objects with null on enumerable

```
string.Join(",", numberList.Where(n => n.Position != null).OrderBy(n => n.Position).Select(n => n.Number))
```